# Change cell color for cells with text - Error Type mismatch

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to write a VBA that changes the color of cells that begin with  specific words ("Enter", "Error", "Used", "Charge No") e.g. "Error! Input does not match material". I'm quite new to VBA and tried different things but I get stuck every time and get the error

> "Type mismatch".

What I got so far is this:

```
Sub highlight()
    Dim cell As Range
                             
    For Each cell In Range("D2:E2").EntireColumn
        If cell.Value = "Enter" Then
            cell.Interior.color = RGB(221, 235, 247) 
        ElseIf cell.Value = "Error" Then
            cell.Interior.color = RGB(253, 145, 145) 
        ElseIf cell.Value = "add Charge No" Then
            cell.Interior.color = RGB(255, 242, 204) 
        ElseIf cell.Value = "Used" Then
            cell.Interior.color = RGB(255, 242, 204) '
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Conditional formatting could do that.  Also `Range("D2:E2").EntireColumn` is 2,097,150 cells to check - you might want to limit the cells it's looking at.

Comment: Aside from my last comment, try `cell.Value Like "Error*" Then`

Comment: I highly recommend to do some research on how to [Use conditional formatting to highlight information](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-conditional-formatting-to-highlight-information-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f). There is no need for VBA at all

Comment: Hi Darren, thanks for your answer. It worked perfectly fine with your idears :)

Comment: I did not fully understand why jet but i will try to get my head around :)

Comment: You should learn how to use conditional formatting, changing cell color using VBA is a static change (if you update the value later, the cell color doesn't change until you run the code again)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a simple screenshot example of how easy life can be using conditional formatting (done in less than five minutes):

[image: Excel conditional formatting screenshot]

In case you prefer not to use conditional formatting because you want to avoid copying the conditional formatting, you might consider using "Paste - Values".

Comment: Hi Dominique, thanks for your answer. I know conditional formatting. However this is not suited in that context due to copy and past from a draft page. I noticed that excel  also copied the conditional rules and over time a sheet contains multiple set of the same rules. To avoid that I tried VBA.

Comment: @SloRi: I just tested: when using "Paste - Values" instead of the regular paste, you can avoid conditional formatting being copied along.

Comment: Ahh ok nice. I didn't know that. Thanks for the information :)